# CISCO WS-C4948-10GE SFP+?

Tags: cisco, sfp, 10gige

I have a pair of CISCO WS-C4948-10GE's that we need to connect to a new switch that has SFP+ and QSFP ports. Is there an X2 module that supports this? If so, can someone name the part number that will work? I have found some information, but want to make sure I have the correct part number for our exact switches.

Per the discussion in the comments, I believe I have a better understanding of things now.

Would I be correct in saying that I need these SR modules on the cisco side: [url]http://www.ebay.com/itm/Cisco-original-used-X2-10GB-SR-V02-/281228948970?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item417a8d35ea[/url]

Then, on the switch with sfp+ ports, I can pick up an SR to SFP+ transceiver like this: [url]http://www.advantageoptics.com/SFP-10G-SR_lp.html?gclid=CKP4s-G27b4CFXQiMgodLD8AQA[/url]

and finally, an SR calbe such as this: [url]http://www.colfaxdirect.com/store/pc/viewPrd.asp?idproduct=1551[/url]

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Your cisco rep would be happy to sell you the right part...give them a call?

Comment: We don't have a cisco rep. These are used switches (can't swing the prices cisco charges new).

Comment: I found these, but have no idea if they will actually work in a 4948: http://www.amazon.com/Cisco-OneX-Converter-Module-CVR-X2-SFP10G/dp/B0030VM08Q/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1401999035&sr=1-1&keywords=x2+sfp%2B

Comment: When you say "Is there an X2 module that supports this?"  What precisely is the problem you're solving?   You want a 3rd party X2 10GE optic?  If so, single mode or multimode?  How long is the fiber shot and is the fiber 50 micron OM3?

Comment: We have the two cisco switches mentioned in the post, and we have a third switch with sfp+ and qsfp ports. We simply need to be able to connect the CISCO WS-C4948-10GE's to the switch that has the SFP+ ports. At this point it doesn't matter how it is done, but I have to make it work. The run would only be 10 feet max at this point. (I know almost nothing about fiber and have never had to use it, so please excuse my ignorance at this point)

Comment: Could I just use a transceiver module? Something like this on the sfp switch side: http://www.advantageoptics.com/SFP-10G-SR_lp.html?gclid=CKP4s-G27b4CFXQiMgodLD8AQA

THen this on the cisco side? http://www.ebay.com/itm/Cisco-original-used-X2-10GB-SR-V02-/281228948970?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item417a8d35ea

I think I may be understanding how this works a bit better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking about [X2 Optics](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Cisco-original-used-X2-10GB-SR-V02-/281228948970?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item417a8d35ea%5b/url%5d), which is what the [c4948-10GE](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-4948-10-gigabit-ethernet-switch/prod_bulletin0900aecd80246560.html) uses; so the ebay picture you listed is definitely one possible option for the 4948's optics.

Whenever you build optical solutions, remember these basic issues:

- Transceiver types must match: In this case you're using [Multimode fiber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-mode_optical_fiber) SR optics.  This transmit format (SR) is part of the [IEEE 802.3ae](http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/802.3ae-2002.html) standard, so just be sure that the transceiver is the same type on both sides. Vendors can be a bit picky about SFP support in their equipment, so be sure the vendor on the other side supports whichever pluggable transceiver you purchase.
- Fiber type must match transceiver type: Buy *OM3* [Multimode fiber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-mode_optical_fiber) cable; the size (50 micron vs. 62.5 micron) shouldn't be a problem for the 10m distance you're considering.
- [Fiber connectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_fiber_connector) must mate with the transceiver type: You need SC connectors on one side and LC connectors on the other side.

*LC Connectors*:
[image: LC Connector]

*SC Connectors*:
[image]

### UDLD

If you're connecting two Cisco switches to each other, turn [UDLD](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3550/software/release/12-1_19_ea1/configuration/guide/3550scg/swudld.html) on the port to protect against unidirectional cabling.

### Debugging

If you have any problems bringing the link up, loop the transceiver to itself with a loose fiber jumper... this means technically you'd want more than just the LC-SC cable, if you don't already have fiber loopback plugs.

You can build your own MMF LC or SC loopback plug with a piece of LC-LC or SC-SC fiber.  Both LC and SC connectors pull apart, and then you just take one of the strands and plug it into the TX and RX of one of the transceivers.  If that transceiver lights up, then you've got a good transceiver.  Conversely, if the transceiver won't loop up, you need to diagnose why (it could be something as simple as your 10GE port is administratively shutdown).

### Non-Cisco optics in IOS

You've mentioned Cisco-branded parts in your question; however, in case you decide to use 3rd party optics in your Cisco, use these commands.

```
Switch(config)#service internal
Switch(config)#service unsupported-transceiver
Switch(config)#no errdisable detect cause gbic-invalid
```

Officially Cisco TAC could bark about this if they see these commands, and occasionally you find a 3rd party pluggable that doesn't work, so YMMV.